# How to implement scrolling for all subviews

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, uiscrollview, scroll

I have a view controller with two subviews: UITableView and UIWebView. Both subviews have a dynamic size. How can I implement scrolling of both subviews in the same time like they stick one to another? I tried to add them to the UIScrollView but still they scroll separately.

Also I've tried to add a UIWebView into a table cell, but then I can't implement a zoom to the UIWebView in the table cell.

Thank you for your help and advice!

Comment: Maybe try to drop your UIWebView into UITableView header or footer, depends if you want to have UIWebView on top of the table or bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a UIScrollView. What you need to do:

- Add both Views (Map view & Table View) to a UIScrollView as subviews
- Disable scrolling for these subviews
- Set the contentSize of the UIScrollView and move them where you want them to be.

This way there will be no scrolling within the subviews but instead they will move (stick) together.

Answer (score 0):

Act as the delegate of both scroll views and implement `scrollViewDidScroll`. For each update you get, check which scroll view it is and set the content offset of the other scroll view to the offset of the scroll view passing you the update.

Answer (score 0):

1. Adding a UITableView and a UIWebView into a UIScrollView will mean that they can scroll together... but what has control? If the UITableView and UIScrollView have active content then iOS is going to be confused about what to scroll and how.
2. Adding a UIWebView into a table cell will zoom if you use:
       [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];